# How can I execute one script using subprocess while the executed script calls another script and terminates itself?

Tags: python, operating-system, synchronization, subprocess, command

I have two scripts working synchronously ,S1 and S2 , in the end of S1 there is

```
os.system("python S2.py") sys.exit()
```

and the same for s2 there is :

```
os.system("python S1.py") sys.exit().
```

they are working fine together,But I'm trying to find a solution to put them in api as a endpoint , I made some search couldn't find a lot except something about subprocess , but if I use it like that it will not continue the process

```
import subprocess

# script1.py
subprocess.call(["python", "s1.py"])
print("continue process")
```

s1 and s2 will do some instructions and insert the results in DB and I want the process after subprocess to continue so i can get the results from DB . is it possible ?